# Android: Storing Image into project directory (files)?

Tags: android, image, file, directory, store

I want to store my Bitmap image into project directory. How can I have access to my project folder or what is the address of my project folder?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to put the images in the `res/drawable` folder. Then, you can access them by using: `R.drawable.name_of_image` (for `name_of_image.png` or `name_of_image.jpg`).

If you want to access them by their original name, you better save them in the `assets` folder. Then, you can access them by using the `AssetManager`:

```
AssetManager am = getResources().getAssets();
try {
    InputStream is = am.open("image.png");
    // use the input stream as you want
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you want to save a programatically created image, you can do:

```
try {
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/imagename.png");
       bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
} catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can't save it to your project directory. I recommend you to read the documentation about how android packages work, because it seems you don't understand.

Comment: Thanks Cristian, Oh no. actually I want to save my image (that I created through program), into res/drawable directory. I read a picture, extracted pixels, then I manipulated the pixels, now I want to save it again in this directory with another name. this is my problem, how can I store this new picture?

Comment: Thanks dear Cristian. I changed my code as you told me but when the program reaches to this line "FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/imagename.png"); " crashes and jumps out.

Comment: thanks dear Cristian for spending your time. This is the picture of log: http://www.4shared.com/photo/mu3f7zBy/log.html

Comment: How did you initialize `context`?

Comment: at the top of class, I wrote "Context context;" Also I tested in Activity but result was the same.

Comment: You declared context, but you haven't initialized. That's why you get a `NullPointerException`. Try changing context by `NameOfYourActivity.this`.

Comment: Thanks so much dear Cristian, I did it with your guide. thanks for your time that you spent for me, thanks.