# shared Preferences and screen orientation

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-camera

Please tell me:

1. How to save the camera image into "sharedpreferences"?
2. After opening the camera and take picture, When I return back to the previous activity, I found the screen is displayed horizontally and it does not return back to it's actual orientation. How can I fix this problem?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not save binary data into *SharedPreferences*.
You could serialize your image into a string value and store it into *SharedPreferences* but this is not what preferences are intended for.

You will be better off saving the image into the database.

As for the screen orientation take a look at this question: [How to make an application ignore screen orientation change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410504/how-to-make-application-completely-ignore-screen-orientation-change-in-android)

Comment: Google and StackOverflow ;) ... like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336865/android-storing-image-into-project-directory-files