# error in saving an image to local database in android application

Tags: android

I am developing an android application in which i have a custom spinner
Below is attached screenshot

I want that all the images that are shown in list.Want to save them locally,Because i am implementing alarm application

http://postimage.org/image/3v8ht71b9/0c807e34/

Has anyone done this before.

I want that when my alarm plays,...this image should come with it..

Thanks in advance
Cool jatt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should save the images to `assets` rather than storing them to database & how to go through that check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336865/android-storing-image-into-project-directory-files).

Thanks.